# Preciso apresentar o produto com o maior faturamento bruto em vendas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

```
SELECT p.descricao_prod
FROM produto p
INNER JOIN venda v ON v.cod_prod = p.codigo
WHERE p.preco = (SELECT MAX(p.preco) FROM produto p)
```

Eu tentei com esse código, mas, ele só me apresenta o produto com maior preço. Porem, preciso do produto com maior faturamento em vendas...

Aqui estão as fotos das tabelas necessárias:

[image: tabela: produtos]

[image: tabela: vendas]

De alguma forma preciso que some as vendas de cada produto pra ver qual da o maior valor, mas, nem imagino como fazer isso...
Alguém pode me ajudar??!!

Comment: Poderia adicionar o DDL das tabelas e um exemplo da saída esperada?

Comment: Nessa modelagem há um possível erro, na tabela de vendas deve ser armazenado o valor do produto no momento em que ele foi vendido, isso porque o produto pode sofrer alteração nos valores, a tabela de vendas serve também como um histórico, recomendo que você realize este ajuste, de qualquer forma vou colocar a resposta com base na sua modelagem atual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na minha visão há um erro na sua modelagem, considere revisar, pois você não grava o valor do produto na tabela venda, imagine o seguinte cenário:

1. Na sua tabela de produtos o valor da caneta é R$ 2,00, você realiza uma venda hoje da última caneta em estoque, e no dia seguinte o comprador da sua empresa compra um novo lote da mesma caneta, mas por um preço maior, então seu preço de venda deixa de ser R$ 2,00 e passa a ser R$ 2,50, se você utiliza como referência o valor cadastrado na tabela de produtos para determinar o valor do seu faturamento, todas as canetas que já foram vendidas assumirão o novo valor que é de R$ 2,50;
2. A tabela de venda representa um fato, e você deve armazenar o valor do produto nela, isso vai te ajudar a responder questões do tipo:

2.1 Quanto custava a caneta em 2020?
2.1 Qual a média do valor da caneta nos últimos 6 meses;

Além disso somente assim vai obter o valor real do seu faturamento.

De qualquer forma eu entendi o seu questionamento, segue a query que acredito ser o que você precisa, quando você alterar sua modelagem, basta alterar **b.preco** por **a.valor** onde valor corresponderá ao valor do produto no momento da venda.

Abaixo ideia da Query com base no seu problema:

1. Realize o join entre a tabela venda e produto;
2. Some o valor total de "venda" por produto;
3. Ordene de forma decrescente (Maior para o menor);
4. Limite o resultado;

Esse modelo é legal porque você pode deixar sua query mais versátil, e apenas manipulando o limit, você poderia mostrar os 5 produtos com maior valor de faturamento por exemplo.

Espero ter ajudado

```
 
select b.codigo, b.descricao_prod, sum(b.preco) as vltotal
 from venda a inner join produto b on (a.cod_prod = b.codigo)
 group by b.codigo, b.descricao_prod
 order by vltotal desc
 limit 1;
```

Comment: Obrigado, amigo. O problema é que é o banco que meu professor passou kkkkkk. Eu tbm acho que faria 200% mais sentido ter o preço ta tabela de vendas. Mas, Os caras gostam de complicar né kkkk.
Muito obrigado pela sua sugestão e por ter mandado uma Query. Ajudou muito!

Comment: Ufaa menos mau :) então está tranquilo, de qualquer forma a explicação é válida para quem utilizar a sua pergunta como referência, espero que te ajude... e se a questão resolveu seu problema, não esqueça de marcá-la como resposta, ótimo dia!